# AMPL: Sum of two specific parameters

Tags: parameters, sum, ampl

I am currently working on a Revenue maximization model in AMPL. One part of the General (!) Revenue Function is:

... + sum {e in E, a in A, z in Z}: (q[z]+u[z]*n[e,z,a])*n[e,z,a]

Now I want to solve it only for a specific a and z e.g.: a=13 and z=Boston

I tried using the following notation but AMPL gives me an error message (Syntax error) for the used ","

sum {e in E, a in A: a="13", z in Z: z="Boston"}: ...

What is wrong and how can I solve the problem? :)

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Here is the error message:
    syntax error
context:  maximize Revenue_GK: sum {i in I} (m[i]+(b[i]*x[i]))*(1-x[i])*(1-t[i]) + sum {e in E,a in A: a="13" >>> , <<<  z in Z: z="Boston"} (q[z]+u[z]*n[e,z,a])*n[e,z,a];

Answer (score 0):

You should specify "such that" conditions at the end of the indexing expression:

```
sum {e in E, a in A, z in Z: a = "13" && z = "Boston"}
```

which can be simplified to

```
sum {e in E, a in {"13"}, z in {"Boston"}}
```